# Adding 1 to an int variable each time a user inputs

Tags: java, eclipse, for-loop

Basically I want my code to scan for a player name and want it to print the player name is player 1. Im just trying to figure out a way to ++ to the 1 every time another payer is created.

```
public void create(int num) {
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please enter the name of your player");
String god = scan.next();
for (int x = 0;  x < god.length(); x++)
{
    System.out.println(god + " is player" + x);
}
```

I understand god.length() is not logical in the statement but I can't think of anything else.

Comment: you need to show more context, you *somehow* already get a `num` handed in, what is that, where is that method called from? The method itself probably should not deal with the player number but the outside logic that calls the method should specify the player number.

Answer (score 1):

Introduce a `currentNumber` `int` field, initialize it to `0` and use it when you create a new player.
At each time a new player is created, you have to increment it of course.

The `int num` parameter in `create()` is helpless.
You don't use it and it doesn't make part of your requirement.

The loop either. You loop as many as the length of the input String retrieved from the scanner.
With "joe" as input you will output :

> joe is player 0
>
> joe is player 1
>
> joe is player 2

Here is a simple code that should address your requirement :

```
 public class MyClass{
    ...
    private int currentNumber = 0;
    ...
    public void create() {
      Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Please enter the name of your player");
      String god = scan.next();
      System.out.println(god + " is player" + ++currentNumber);
     }
     ...
}
```